# MS Access numerical field with NULL VALUE through textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am writting Access VBA application. I created following table using access sql query

```
create table tblSummary
(
    medicine_id autoincrement primary key,
    medicine_type varchar(20) not null,
    user_id long null
);

 1. medicine_id --> Autoincrement 
 2. medicine_type --> Mandatory field
 3. user_id --> Optional field
```

[image]

```
medicine_id is getting through textbox.value
medicine_type is getting through combobox.value
user_id is getting through textbox.value (optional field)

insert into tblSummary (medicine_id,medicine_type,user_id) values(1,"tablet",10);
insert into tblSummary (medicine_id,medicine_type,user_id) values(2,"drop",20);
```

without entering optional field user_id, I tried to submit using following query

```
insert into tblSummary (medicine_id,medicine_type,user_id) values(3,"capsule",'');
```

I am getting systax error. If user does not enter any value in the textbox for the option field (here it is user_id) i want to store user_id field with blank value. As it is numerical field i could not use "" double quote with blank.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't insert the autonumber:

```
insert into tblSummary (medicine_type,user_id) values("capsule",10);
```

Second, if no user_id, insert *Null*:

```
insert into tblSummary (medicine_type,user_id) values("capsule",Null);
```

or leave it out:

```
insert into tblSummary (medicine_type) values("capsule");
```